# How to select Value from Combo Box in DataGrid

Tags: winforms

I have 8 columns in Datagrid. 8th Column is Combo Box. I have defined a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn for this. I have "id" and "Name" to that combo box.

Now I have two questions

1. Which event I can use if I want to select an item, then immediately triggers. CellValueChanged event is only triggering after you click some where.
2. I found CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, but this is not giving me "id". It gives me only "name" by using datagrid.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue; How to get the "ID"

my purpose is to get the "id" as soon as some one select an item. Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution. If there is any other solution you are welcome

I got this using event handler..

add the below line just after adding items to Combo box

// We will handle these events of the DataGridView
            dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellEndEdit);
            dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);
        }

```
    void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbm != null)
        {
            // Here we will remove the subscription for selected index changed
            cbm.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(cbm_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
    }

    void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Here try to add subscription for selected index changed event
        if (e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            cbm = (ComboBox)e.Control;
            if (cbm != null)
            {
                cbm.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cbm_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }
            currentCell = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell;
        }
    }

    void cbm_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Invoke method if the selection changed event occurs
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(EndEdit));
    }

    void EndEdit()
    {
        // Change the content of appropriate cell when selected index changes
        if (cbm != null)
        {
            DataRowView drv = cbm.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
            if (drv != null)
            {
                this.dataGridView1[currentCell.ColumnIndex + 1, currentCell.RowIndex].Value = drv[2].ToString();
                this.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```